# C++ Dereferencing Pointer. Why is this changing?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why placing the * outside the parenthesis ends up changing the value. I understand why the 2 prints out, however I don't understand why the 3 prints out. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
int main()
{
     //delcaring typedef of boxes
     typedef int boxes[2][2];

     //delcaring variables that are going to be placed into the boxes
     int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8;

     //declaring two boxes variables and storing variables
     boxes myBox={{a,b},{c,d}};
     boxes myBox2={{e,f},{g,h}};

     //placing those boxes into a pointer boxes array
     boxes *x[2][2]={{&myBox,&myBox2,},{&myBox,&myBox2}};

    //testing code
    cout<<(*x[0][0])[0][1]<<endl;  //prints out 2
    cout<<*(x[0][0])[0][1]<<endl;  //prints out 3

}
```

Comment: Consider the difference after reviewing (a) what you're doing, and (b) [the operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of all the operators involved.

Comment: I also recommend that you draw out your arrays on paper, using boxes for each element of an array, and arrows for pointers. Might help you get a better  overview of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a lot of multiplication and parentheses in these sorts of problems, it's important to take into account operator precedence. The reason it's outputting 3, is because your program reads

`*(x[0][0])[0][1]`

as

`*((x[0][0])[0][1])`

Thus, you can see that in this it is dereferencing the entire thing, rather than just the `(x[0][0])`